# Obtaining an app ID on behalf of my employer

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I am a programmer employed by a company to develop a web app owned by that company. We allow users to log in with Twitter. We would like to allow users to log in with Facebook. For this we require tokens to plug in to OAuth 2.

The snag is that so far as I can determine, Facebook require that apps are owned by a Facebook user, and a that Facebook user uniquely identify a natural person. I don’t want to register using my existing Facebook ID; my work identity is not relevant to friends and family, and besides, I will not be an employee of the company indefinitely. I have not found any information yet to indicate I can hand the ownership of the app to another developer, though I assume such a process must logically be required. I could violate the Facebook terms and create a new ID to register the app with, or I could attempt to coach the CEO of the company (who is not a programmer) through the process of registering for an app. This will be complicated by the fact that I can’t even get past step 1 so I can’t rehearse the process.

So my programming question is, is there a way I have not yet discovered that Facebook allows companies to delegate the chore of registering an app? Failing that, has anyone published a route through Facebook’s developer’s maze to get the OAuth keys in the minimum of steps?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8434865/create-new-app-from-business-account I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the app using your facebook account, initially, then you can create a Facebook Group called something like "My App Admins" - then get anybody who is important in the company to join that Facebook Group (including yourself) Then in the app settings, set that group as an admin of the app. (you can also create seperate groups for insights users, developers and testers)

Anybody in that group will now be an administrator. That way the company can control access to the app by adding or removing people from that group.

It is not an ideal solution. Facebook want to be able to link application developer accounts to real people - this is a way of preventing spamming etc.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: This seems to be working, though I have to persuade my colleagues to verify, validate, and generally vamp their Facebook IDs so that I can add them. :-)